# Call a function inside promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to find a way to call the method pageLoader.fetch twice in this promise. I already tried to separate it in a new promise but I get undefined when I try to get the variable links[0]. How to do this?

```
pageLoader
  .fetch(url)
  .then(function(data) {
    links = html.orderdList(data);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return pageLoader.fetch(links[0]);
    //links[0] is undefined in the next line!?
  })
  .then(
    pageLoader
      .fetch(links[0])
      .then(function(innerLinks) {
        calLinks = html.unorderList(innerLinks);
      })
      .then(function() {
        return pageLoader.fetch("http:///example.com");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  );
```

Comment: the `return` statement stops execution of the current function.

Comment: note: `.then(
    pageLoader
      .fetch ...` - is wrong ... `.then` only works if you supply a function as an argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You have some redundant, `then()`s, which I've removed. It's not clear why you are calling `pageLoader.fetch(links[0])` twice. Does it return different results?

You also look like you are setting some global variable (`links` & `calLinks` for example), but it's not clear how you will access them asynchronously.

This should work a little better, but given the above, it may still have issues:

```
pageLoader.fetch(url)
.then(function(data) {
  links = html.orderdList(data); // <-- are these global or should you have a var?; 
  return pageLoader.fetch(links[0]);
})
.then(function(link) { // <-- did you want to do something with the return from above?
  return pageLoader.fetch(links[0])
})
.then(function(innerLinks) {
    calLinks = html.unorderList(innerLinks); // <-- are these global?;
    return pageLoader.fetch("http:///example.com");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: pageLoader.fetch(links[0]) returns new urls taken from pageLoader.fetch(url) page

Comment: @Jason - I see, you are calling it twice with the same index `pageLoader.fetch(links[0])` which is why I was confused.

Comment: link and calLinks are global

Answer (score 1):

The line `.then(pageLoader.fetch(links[0])...)` is not doing what you probably want it to be doing. Calling it like that is the equivalent of doing this:

```
var myCallback = pageLoader.fetch(links[0]).then().then().catch();

pageLoader
  .fetch(url)
  .then(function(data) {
    links = html.orderdList(data);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return pageLoader.fetch(links[0]);
  })
  .then(myCallback)
```

Your second fetch is actually being immediately executed before everything else and the *result* of that is being passed as the callback. You probably want to not call that code until the first `fetch` has happened, so you'll want to wrap it in a function (like with your other `.then()` statements).

I might also suggest that you could greatly simplify your code:

```
pageLoader
  .fetch(url)
  .then(function(data) {
    // this is called when the first fetch() returns
    links = html.orderdList(data);
    return pageLoader.fetch(links[0]);
    // returning a promise means that following .then()
    // statements will act on the returned promise rather than the original
  })
  .then(function(innerLinks) {
    // this is called when the second fetch() returns
    calLinks = html.unorderList(innerLinks);
    return pageLoader.fetch("http:///example.com");
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // this is called if the original promise or any of
    // the promises returned in the .then() callbacks throw errors
  });
```

I found this article to be very helpful in explaining the best ways to use Promises, and some of the mistakes that can happen: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html